# How to pass form value to PHP variable with AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Having issues anyone has any ideas? I have only posted was is necessary for the code. I basically have an HTML form I want to pull the value from a field on a form before it's submitted run an ajax call and populate another field. I think if I could get that Txt that is entered in the form over to a PHP variable on the modcreate.php it will work. because if I manually enter the details without the variable it works.

mainpage.php

Relevant parts from form

```
  <tr>
    <th>Service Tag:</th>
    <th><input type="text" id="inputTag" name="inputTag" value="" onblur="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"></td>
  </tr>
```

and

```
  <tr>
    <th>Model:</th>
    <th>
       <input type="text" id="inputModel" name="inputModel" value=""> 
       <a href="#" id="updateBtn">Populate</a>
       <div id="spinner">
          <img src="\images\ajax-load.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
       </div>
    </th>
  </tr>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="\js\jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $('#updateBtn').click( function(e) {
    //to disable the click from going to next page
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url: "modcreate.php",
       data: { 'txt1': $('#inputTag').val() },
       success: function(data) {
       }
    });
 });
 </script>
```

modcreate.php

```
<?php 

$field1value = $_GET['txt1'];
    $file_string = file_get_contents('blahblah.com/'.$field1value);
    preg_match("/<title>Product Support for (.+)\| Dell/i", $file_string, $matches);
    $print = "$matches[1]";
    echo $print;
?>
```

******Solution******
my ajax call was missing the part where it sent the data back to the form field

here is what the working ajax looks like now  thanks guys for all the pointers

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="\js\jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $('#updateBtn').click(function(e){
     //to disable the click from going to next page
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url: "modcreate.php",
         data: { 'txt1': $('#inputTag').val() },
         success: function(data) {
            $('#inputModel').val(data); //this was the missing part
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Is modcreate.php giving you any results if you go to it directly? (ex: navigate to modcreate.php?txt1=somethinghere

Comment: You have to define Your AJAX method `type:"POST"` or `type:"GET"`

Comment: @AdamZapp - jQuery defaults to `GET` - it's not necessary to set it.

Comment: Please define 'Having Issues'

Comment: What specific problem are you having? One thing I see missing is the form submit, which you would presumably want to call from within your ajax success function.

Comment: @Joao I did as advised (modcreate.php?txt1=somethinghere) and it printed the results correctly. Additionally prior to posting the intial question I tried Setting the ajax type to "post"  and  using $_POST['txt1'] instead of GET and had the same just a blank page when navigating

Comment: I figured out was doing wrong.... @mayabelle you pointed me in the right direction i had forgot to report the data back to the model form field..... with  $('#inputModel').val(data); after the success

Comment: I know this is not codereview but seemed important enough. You need better variable naming, `$field1Value` says nothing and is a lie waiting to happen when the form needs to get another field ahead of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $('#updateBtn').click(function(e){
    //to disable the click from going to next page
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url: "modcreate.php",
            data: 'data="{ "txt1": '+$('#inputTag').val()+' }"',
            success: function(data){


          }
     }
);
});
</script>
```

On server side:

```
$income_data = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);
$field1value = $income_data['txt1'];
```

Comment: thank you however I just got it working before seeing this by adding  $('#inputModel').val(data); after my ajax success. Im not sure if it would work with the code you supplied but I will keep it incase I run into issues with the code I got working. Unless the method you posted has advantages over my working code?

Comment: Note missing semicolon on the end of `$field1value = $income_data['txt1']'` to be put in place of last `'`

Comment: Data can be a hash, it's much more easy to write. E.g.: data: { 'txt1': value, 'var2': value }